# Creating Sub Folders in FTP Folder in C# Windows Applications

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to use a text box with date picker to select the date. Based on the selected date, when I click on "go" button, sub folders should be created in FTP Folder for that date, month and year that is given in text box.

This should be done using windows application. Can you please tell me how I can do this?

Below is the code for selecting the date using date picker and displaying the message in message box. But instead of displaying the message I need to create sub folders in FTP Folder for that date month and year that is present in text box.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime iDate;
    iDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    MessageBox.Show("Selected date is " + iDate);
}
```

and to create folder in FTP server the code I had used is

```
using System.Net;

private void CreateDirectoryFTP(string directory)
{
    string path = @"/" + directory;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(FtpHost + path);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUser, FtpPass);
    try
    {
       request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //directory exists
    }
}
```

This is used below `button1_click` event and when I am calling this method in `button1_click` event in this way `CreateDirectoryFTP(string directory)` it is giving an error

> Invalid expression term string

but folders should be created when I click the button. Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: I think you have trouble with basic c#. When you want to call `CreateDirectoryFTP` you want to pass _a string representing the folder name_. For example something like `CreateDirectoryFTP(iDate.ToShortDateString());`

Comment: How did you call `CreateDirectoryFTP` in your `button1_click` event?

Comment: You code doesnt show you using the CreateDirectoryFTP function

Comment: I had call in this way in my button_click event CreateDirectoryFTP(string directory);  It shows an error "Invalid expression term string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method declaration you are indicating that the parameter `dictionary` is of type `string`. When you want to call your method inside your `button1_click` event, you just have to pass any `string` but without using the term `string` before it again.

Example:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string directory = @"\Path\You\Want\To\Pass";
    DateTime iDate;
    iDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    CreateDirectoryFTP(directory, iDate); // You directly pass the variable to the method
}
```

Or you could pass it directly if you don't want to use a variable to pass the path:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime iDate;
    iDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    CreateDirectoryFTP(@"\Path\You\Want\To\Pass", iDate);
}
```

To create subfolders, pass the date to the method `CreateDirectoryFTP`:

```
private void CreateDirectoryFTP(string directory, DateTime date)
{
    string path = @"/" + directory;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(FtpHost + path);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUser, FtpPass);
    try
    {
        request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //directory exists
    }

    string pathToDay = path + "/" + date.Day.ToString();
    // And now you can create the subfolder like you did it for the main folder

    string pathToMonth = path + "/" + date.Month.ToString();
    // Also with the month and the year you can do it like you did it for the main folder
}
```

Comment: It is getting called but sub folders are not created in FTP Folder for the selected date,month and year if my given date in text box is 15/05/2016 i need to get folders for 15 ,5,2016 totally i need 3 folders in my FTP server.How can i do this

Comment: You can pass the date to your `CreateDirectoryFTP` method and then create subfolders by accessing `date.Day`, `date.Month` and `date.Year`.

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass this date.Day, date.Month and date.Year to create directory FTP

Comment: string path = @"Here i had given the ftp link path" + directory; 
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(here ftp user name, here ftp password);
in this way i had provided my credentials.But i am unable to create folder for month,date and year on ftp server.how can i create folder for date,month and year on ftp server using above code.can you please help me out

Comment: i had use the above modified code as it is when i using this code i am getting  an run-time exception.  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." at FTP host here do i need to pass my FTP server link in the place of FTP host.